# Eliminar tuplas de una tabla cada cierto tiempo en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo estas dos tablas
Codigos:

```
CREATE TABLE `codigos` (
 `ID_USUARIO` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `CODIGO` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
 `HORA` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `codigos`
--

INSERT INTO `codigos` (`ID_USUARIO`, `CODIGO`, `HORA`) VALUES
(12, '8288', '13:00:54');
```

Y usuarios:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nombre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `edad` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `usuario` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `contraseña` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `admin` varchar(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuarios`
--

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`ID`, `nombre`, `edad`, `email`, `usuario`, `contraseña`, `status`, `admin`) VALUES
(12, 'Manuel Salazar', 18, 'tongo@gmail.com', 'Manuel', '123456&t', '0', '0');
```

Estoy trabajando en un sistema en el cual, cuando te registras, este te manda un código de confirmación de cuenta al correo con el que  te registraste, y en caso de ponerlo el status de la cuenta cambia a 1 y la tupla en la tabla códigos se elimina.

Lo que quiero hacer es que, si el usuario no confirma su correo electrónico en una hora, la tupla del código y la de el usuario se eliminen.
Para que se tenga que registrar otra vez.

Hasta ahora llevo esto:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT Eliminar_no_confirmadas
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE 
    DO
    BEGIN
       delete from usuarios where ID= (select ID_USUARIO from codigos  WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`FECHA`)<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-1*3600))
      DELETE FROM codigos WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`HORA`) <(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-1*3600);
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero no funciona y al correrlo me manda un error extraño.

Estoy usando MySQL con PhpMyAdmin

Comment: y cual es el error extraño???

Comment: Este: Sorry an unexpected error happened!

Comment: Te falta un `;` al final del primer `DELETE`

Comment: Aun asi no funciona, no elimina nada.

Comment: Donde está la columna `ID_USUARIO` en la tabla de usuarios?

Comment: En ninguna parte